# How to convert nii format file into 2D image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a file with .nii extension. I don't know how to convert a .nii file into 2D format.My question is while converting .nii file into 2D, am I losing some information about the file.Which format is good? dicom or png or bmp.

```
nii = load_nii('im.nii');
size(nii.img);
```

returns

```
ans =

    39   305   305
```

and it is in uint8 format

May I use squeeze or resize?How to apply resize to this image;whether it lose information?

Comment: i want to convert this image into 2d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can manipulate the image/sequence as you would with any array.

Here is a simple example with data available from the NIH [here](http://nifti.nimh.nih.gov/nifti-1/data).

The data set is in 4D and is named "filtered_func_data.nii".

Let's load the dataset and access the `img` field of the resulting structure:

```
S = load_nii('filtered_func_data.nii')
```

Here, S is a structure with the following fields:

```
S = 

           hdr: [1x1 struct]
      filetype: 2
    fileprefix: 'filtered_func_data'
       machine: 'ieee-be'
           img: [4-D int16]
      original: [1x1 struct]
```

And we can access the image data with the field `img` (you already figured that out):

```
A = S.img
```

If we check the size, we get:

```
size(A)

ans =

    64    64    21   180
```

So the dataset consists in 64x64 images with a depth/number of slices of 21 and a number of frames of 180.

At this point we can manipulate `A` as we like to reshape, resize or anything.

Here is a simple code (animated gif) to loop through each slice of the 1st timepoint in the 4D array:

```
NumSlices = size(A,3)

figure(1)
filename = 'MRI_GIF.gif';

for k = 1:NumSlices

    imshow(A(:,:,k,1),[])
    drawnow

    frame = getframe(1);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
    if k == 1;
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');
    end

    pause(.1)
end
```

Output:

[image]

Which looks pretty nice to me.

So in your case, you get a size of `[39 305 305]` and you can apply the same manipulations I did to play around with your data set, which is in 3D.

**EDIT**
With your data it's the same:

```
S = load_nii('Subject01.nii');

A = S.img;

NumSlices = size(A,3);
```

And then, if you want a 2D image you need to select a slice in the 3D array.

For example, the first slice is accessed like so:

```
A(:,:,1)
```

And so on for the rest.

[image]

To save images as png, use [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep it looks like it. Although it seems that it would make more sense to be 305x305 but you can try to permute the dataset and display it to make sure.

Comment: The number of slices is the 3rd dimension, so in this case it looks like its 305. That looks weird though it would make more sense if the image was 305x305 and there were 39 slices

Comment: you can put it in a hosting website and I'll look at it if you want.

Comment: Mhh I would think of Dropbox or Google Drive maybe?

Comment: Alright I tried with your data and it works fine. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So do you need more help?

Comment: Yes you can. As for the resize part I have no idea.

Comment: check my edited answer. You need to access a single image like A(:,:,1) to save in a png.

Comment: why divided by 255.i tried it.i cant view the image using imshow('Sub.png');only a black strip is shown