# Convert .png files to .nii (NiFti files)

Tags: python, matlab, conv-neural-network, file-format

I'm currently working in a project which handles `.nii` files from `neuro images`. I converted that file into 80 `.png` files. Now I need to combine those 80 `.png` into `.nii` files again.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use necessary tags. And do share some code on how are you converting .nii file to .png file. 
Also, be clear on what you are using python or matlab ??

Comment: i have the .nii file converted to 80 .png files in matlab. But i need a way to merge them back either in python or in matlab

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641295/6390175

Comment: this is from nii to 2d. I need to merge these converted 2d back to nii

Comment: You can start by showing the snippet of code where you are converting .nii files to .png files.

Answer (score 1):

The strict answer is no, you can't do it. Because png files do not contain those information needed for NIfTI file.

However if you don't care whether the coordinate and left-right information is correct or not, you could generate a fake nii file. You can read your png files (I suppose they have the same dimension) using a `for` loop:

```
for i = 1:numberOfPNG_file
    img(:,:,i) = imread(png_Files{i});
end
```

The you can use the Matlab [NIfTI tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42997-xiangruili-dicm2nii) to create nii file:

```
nii = nii_tool('init', img);
nii_tool('save', nii, 'my_nii.nii');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    %step 1: get the names of the files
            files=dir('*.png');
            file_names={files.name}';

    %step 2: sort the files

            %extract the numbers
            %Here, the format of the name shoul be enterd and %d should replate the
            %number, this is so that the files will be load in the right order
              filenum = cellfun(@(x)sscanf(x,'%d.png'), file_names);
            % sort them, and get the sorting order
              [~,Sidx] = sort(filenum) ;
            % use to this sorting order to sort the filenames
              SortedFilenames = file_names(Sidx);

   %step 3: combine images to single matrix:
            %get number of files
            num_of_files=numel(SortedFilenames);
            for i=1:num_of_files
                nifti_mat(:,:,i)=imread(SortedFilenames{i});
            end
  %step 4: conver to nifti and save:
            filename='here_goes_the_name_of_the_file';
            niftiwrite(nifti_mat,filename);
```